# OS X stuck at blue screen after installing TeamViewer Host and rebooting

Tags: macos, teamviewer

I installed TeamViewer Host on my Mac running OS X 10.6. After I rebooted the machine, it wouldn't show the login screen anymore, but only show a blue screen. This blue screen would change color repeatedly.

I can't get into the system to uninstall TeamViewer, so what can I do now?

<sub>I put this here for reference because I just ran into the issue and couldn't find a solution on the internet anywhere.</sub>

<sub><sub>Yes. Macs have blue screens. Sort of.</sub></sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot your Mac, and immediately after booting, hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>. It will boot into Single User Mode, where you can modify your existing file system.

Enter the following:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
/sbin/mount -uw /
```

Now, let's delete the Launch Agents and Daemons that TeamViewer Host installed, which are the possible cause of the window server crashing:

```
rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.teamviewer*
rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer*
```

Finally, reboot your Mac by entering:

```
reboot
```

You'll be able to log in again. To completely uninstall TeamViewer Host, run its uninstaller from */Applications*.